# Getting Daily Weather Forecasts from OpenWeatherMap API using Flutter

Tags: api, openweathermap, dart-http, android-studio-4.2, weatherdata

i have an issue with OpenWeatherMap API for hourly weather forecasts. i retrieved the 5 day/3 hours weather data from this api. But now i want daily weather forecasts. i am using this api but this one gives me this error, i tried many times but it gives me the same error.

```
{
"cod": 401,
"message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."
}
```

meanwhile i am using this api for getting daily weather forecasts

```
https://pro.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?lat=21&lon=39&appid=58b73781d0f050d557b4ac143bb61b0c
```

kindly suggest me the some solution that why i am unable to get the response for daily weather forecasts.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation states:](http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401)

> You can get the error 401 in the following cases:
>
> - You did not specify your API key in API request.
> - Your API key is not activated yet. Within the next couple of hours, it will be activated and ready to use.
> - You are using wrong API key in API request. Please, check your right API key in personal account.
> - You are using a Free subscription and try requesting data available in other subscriptions . For example, 16 days/daily forecast API, any
>   historical weather data, Weather maps 2.0, etc). Please, check your
>   subscription in your personal account

If you subscribe to the openweathermap api, it will provide you with an api key to access the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [the help page on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to format your posts in the future. You can refer to how this one was edited for a quick glance.